# Appropriate cookie domain for Django dev server running multiple sites

Tags: python, django

I have multiple Django dev sites running locally like `http://localhost:8000`, `http://localhost:8001`, `http://localhost:8002`, etc.

Originally, I had SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN and CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN set to '' or `127.0.0.1` but this causes each site to overwrite the other's cookies, causing me to have to login every time I switch between sites. I tried using `127.0.0.1:<port>` but that had no effect.

How do I get these sites to use separate cookies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution to this problem is to use local domain name resolution to reach each of your different development servers.  If you leave [SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain) as None, then the returned cookie is a standard domain cookie and will have the same domain as the request.

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file) which describes how to add local host file entries.

With a hosts file like this:

```
127.0.0.1 www.testserver1.com www.testserver2.com
```

You could then access each of your different test servers at:

```
http://www.testserver1.com:8000
http://www.testserver2.com:8001
```

I haven't tried this, but I believe it should work.

Alternatively, as per Mikhail's answer, use a different session cookie name for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are shared across ports for the same domain according to various RFCs (see e.g. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-8.5). So this is not django-specific.

I think you could use different SESSION_COOKIE_NAME to have at least sessions separated.